# Why does Table take so much longer than its constituent computations?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, timing

I have a 10x5x`n` list, which I'll call `data`,

```
data = RandomInteger[{-500, 500}, {10, 5, n}];
```

and a 5x2 list

```
coeffs={{0., -0.951057, -0.587785, 0.587785, 0.951057},
        {1., 0.309017, -0.809017, -0.809017, 0.309017}}
```

For each 5x`n` `nestedList` inside `data`, I want to map it using `coeffs.nestedList`, so that my overall code would look like

```
newData=Table[coeffs.nestedList,{nestedList,data}]
```

However, for large `n`, we start to see a huge difference in the time it takes to run the above line of code and the time it takes to run the constituent computations.

```
componentTime = Total@Table[First@RepeatedTiming[coeffs.nestedList], {nestedList, data}];
tableTime = First@RepeatedTiming[Table[coeffs.nestedList, {nestedList, data}]];
```

Consider the difference between `componentTime` and `tableTime` as `n` increases:

[image: Timings for componentTime and tableTime vs n]

I would expect `tableTime` to be slightly longer than `componentTime`, but not by that much. Why is there such a large discrepancy between the summed time it takes for the components in `Table` to execute and the time it takes for the table itself to be constructed? Is there a way to minimize this discrepancy, or a way to formulate the mapping so that it avoids it altogether?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it has to do with how often data is copied out of the packed array `data`.  If we unpack `data` to level `1`, the timings are equal.

```
n = 1 * 10^7;
data = Identity /@ RandomInteger[{-500, 500}, {10, 5, n}];
componentTime = 
  Total@Table[
    First@RepeatedTiming[coeffs . nestedList], {nestedList, data}];
tableTime = 
  First@RepeatedTiming[Table[coeffs . nestedList, {nestedList, data}]];
{componentTime, tableTime}

(*  {0.594324, 0.590828}  *)
```

A packed array is basically a C language array plus metadata (see below for more). An unpacked array is a linked list of lists or packed subarrays, which can be referenced by pointers instead of being copied.  Having `RepeatedTiming` outside of `Table` means the subarrays represented by `nestedList` are repeatedly copied, whereas when `RepeatedTiming` in inside `Table`, each subarray is copied once and reused.

References:

- [What is a Mathematica packed array?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array)
- [packed-arrays](/questions/tagged/packed-arrays)

Comment: Hi, could you explain what is unpacking the data? Or is there any reference? Thanks!

Comment: @H.Zhou See updated answer. :)

Comment: Regarding your edit: since having `RepeatedTiming` outside of `Table` copies the data each time, does this mean that the extra time in `tableTime` is just an artifact of `RepeatedTiming` and not time that one would actually have to worry about when running the code normally? Or is there an actual performance benefit to unpacking the data in the code?

Comment: @az123p Yes, I think the extra time is an artifact, or more accurately, the faster time is an artifact. The table has 10 data reads plus 10 dot products. The data reads are not repeated when `Repeated` timing is inside `Table`; only the dot products are repeated.

Comment: I see! Thanks for the help.

Comment: @az123p You're welcome. Thanks for the accept. :)